# Start X-application at boot

Tags: linux, x11, gui

I have x-application which monitors remote object and displays corresponding picture on the screen.
If I run startx and then from another terminal start this application it starts successfully and displays all what msut be disaplyed. Without running startx application doesn't start saying it unable to connect to display. Reasonably. X11 is not started.
How to start this application (including X11, of cause) at boot time?
Without login (Linux box doesn't have keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cron` to start programs/scripts at boot. [Install cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802337/how-to-install-cron) and use `crontab -e` to edit the cron file for the current user. Add a line like the following

```
@reboot /path/to/program --options
```

Save and close. The program should run at boot even without login.

If your program/script isn't starting, make sure the cron service is enabled.

```
systemctl status cron
```

If it is disabled use the following to enable the service:

```
systemctl enable cron
```

Comment: Is it good to call xinit this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "is it good". This is a way to call a program at boot and works the same way you would call the program on the command line. `cron` is a widely used program to run scheduled tasks. You can use `cron` to run programs every X hours/days/months but it also supports running programs on boot instead of at incremental times. If you need to start applications in a specific order, you could write a simple shell script which starts them in the order needed, and simply kickoff that script at boot with `cron`